# Why not add reference and multi-dimensional array to awk language

Tags: awk

I'm wondering is there any implementation of awk that has reference(like in perl) or something similar to build complex data structure?
Adding such feature would make awk more powerful.
Will posix standard adds such kind of feature in future?

Comment: My first reaction is "Why bother? Use Perl".  You might find something at http://awk.info/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multidimensional arrays are supported in gawk.](http://www.gnu.org/manual/gawk/html_node/Multi_002ddimensional.html)

From the manual:

```
 {
      if (max_nf < NF)
           max_nf = NF
      max_nr = NR
      for (x = 1; x <= NF; x++)
           vector[x, NR] = $x
 }
```

References are not, and I think referencing is not "the awk way".

HTH!

Comment: They are more like pseudo multidimensional arrays. Awk basically takes the comma operator and concatenates the two array indicies with the ascii File Separator and then treats that as a uni-dimensional index.  To re-separate the two indicies/keys you need to do a `split()` on `SUBSEP`

Comment: @SiegeX Yep. That's the way it works and I think it's a pretty clever way to add the feature. In the other hand, it seems that the OP don't care, as he/she did not commented nor voted ...

Comment: yep, dontcha hate that. Here is +1 for effort

Comment: @SiegeX Thanks. I don't understand some behaviors here, but I guess it's my lack of imagination :). The OP for example had downvoted 213 times and upvoted only 93. With that record, it's clear that SO is not useful for him/her. Why keep coming?